# regex in php only match url and content inside brackets and quotes marks

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following text entered on a textarea and I want to parse from this text the 3 urls and if it has [ ] get the content in a format like: url["key","value"] I've been trying to solve it through regex, but am failing using this: /(\w.+?)[(( ?)"(.*?)"),("(.*?)")]/

> uploads/documents/home4.jpg[ " nosotros "," Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."] ,  uploads/documents/home4.jpg [" servicios ","Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."] ,
>
> http://lorempixel.com/300/300 [" tecnologias ","Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."]

I do not use regular expressions much and am kinda of stuck any help if very appreciated :)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(\w.*?)\[([^\]]*)\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBXBWP/3)

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$re = '/(\w.*?)\[([^\]]*)\]/';
$str = 'uploads/documents/home4.jpg[ " nosotros "," Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."] , uploads/documents/home4.jpg [" servicios ","Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."] ,

http://lorempixel.com/300/300 [" tecnologias ","Somos una asociación civil sin fines de lucro, formada por padres y madres con hijos con problemas de audición, que nos hemos organizado a raíz de los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, por la falta de apoyo para la inclusión de nuestros hijos."]
';

$list=[[]];
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$cnt=0;
$index=0;
for($i=1;$i<count($matches);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<3;$j++) 
        $list[$cnt++][$index]=$matches[$i][$j];
    $cnt=0;
    $index=1;
}
print_r($list);
?>
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/qQfDjY)